# Apply some easing into UIImageView animation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using the following to make a UIImageView slide a little bit forward, and then slide back farther for a parallax scrolling effect.

Code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{
    spendrBckGrnd.frame = CGRectMake(spendrBckGrnd.frame.origin.x + 20, 0, spendrBckGrnd.frame.size.width, spendrBckGrnd.frame.size.height);
}];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f animations:^{
    spendrBckGrnd.frame = CGRectMake(spendrBckGrnd.frame.origin.x - 80, 0, spendrBckGrnd.frame.size.width, spendrBckGrnd.frame.size.height);
}];
```

I am wondering how I might go about applying some easing into the animation, right now if just abruptly slides back and forth quickly. I would like to ease into and out of the sliding animations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the second animation block *after* the first one completes.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{
    spendrBckGrnd.frame = CGRectMake(spendrBckGrnd.frame.origin.x + 20, 0, spendrBckGrnd.frame.size.width, spendrBckGrnd.frame.size.height);
} completion:^{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^(BOOL finished){
        spendrBckGrnd.frame = CGRectMake(spendrBckGrnd.frame.origin.x - 80, 0, spendrBckGrnd.frame.size.width, spendrBckGrnd.frame.size.height);
    }];
}];
```

Comment: That was it, can't believe I didn't catch that other static method from UIView. BTW, your code works just like I need but you need to add (BOOL finished) to the second block I believe

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial on UIView animation
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_uiview-animations/

UIView has a method

```
//   [UIView animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval) delay:(NSTimeInterval) options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)animations:^(void)animations completion:^(BOOL finished)completion];
typedef enum {
        UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut,         // slow at beginning and end
        UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn,            // slow at beginning
        UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut,           // slow at end
        UIViewAnimationCurveLinear
    }
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6f
                delay:0.1f
                options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                animations:^{
                        [starView setCenter:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
                        [starView setAlpha:0.0f];
                }
                completion:^(BOOL finished){
                            [starView removeFromSuperview];
                            points++;
                }
    ];
```

Also check out this control on github that creates a parallax effect using a custom container view, much like the top view of Path's timeline.
https://github.com/modocache/MDCParallaxView

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut       animations:^(void){
//do your animations
} completion:^(BOOL finished){

}];
```